# Display information: Redirect to new page or show pop-up?

Tags: usability, website-design, user-expectation, popup

I have searched for similar questions but they couldn't really answer the problem in my case.

I have designed a profile page where users can display their earned titles trough a reputation system. When users click on these titles, it should display information about how to earn this title and which user already unlocked this title.

Usability-wise:

> **Should I show this information on a new page, or should I use a pop-up for this?**

Here are a few mockups I have created so far.

## User clicks on a title to display more information

[image]

## (1) Displaying information on a new page

[image]

## (2) Displaying information with a pop-up

[image]

Usability-wise, what would be the best approach in this situation? Is there any research regarding this problem, or should I display this completely differently?

Answer (score 2):

I am not profesional web designer, just stumbled upon this and giving my humble opinion.

Using pop-ups is usually better when the information in the opened window is just for you to read – no work in the pop up (consider even scrolling). You dont want to make the user go back to previous site, whenever he wants to check something that he will probably spend few seconds on.

On the other hand if you are expecting the user to spend more time on the given information or if given information contains more links to other websites and you can expect the user to go back to this page (he may be confused what did he click on previously), then going for a page may be better solution. It is also easier for user to send link to this page to a friend (if this behavior is expected)

Comment: I think this is true. Also modals have accessibility issues

It really depends on whether you'll be going back to the parent page and using info in the modal for reference without interacting much with it

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I indeed want to show the user more information about this title. If they then decide to show more titles available they would click on 'see all titles', which would be a conscious choice. I'll stick with the pop-up for now until I ran some user-tests.

Answer (score 0):

The modal option is probably better in this situation for desktop and probably tablet views, however just be weary of how to do this on a mobile device. Of course the structure of your website would play a part in this and whether this is even accessible or not on mobile devices is another question you should ask.